# Leer las etiquetas environment de otros docker en compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Quiero saber si se puede hacer y si es así cómo hacerlo, como poder **leer las etiquetas de entorno de otros dockers**.

Les dejo un ejemplo de lo que he visto y no consigo encontrar información con la que entender cómo lo hace (docker compose):

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html

  nginx:
    image: tobi312/php:7.4-fpm-nginx-alpine-arm
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@mail.com
volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhostd:
  confd:
```

**En este ejemplo se puede ver que**: los contenedores `nginx-proxy` y `letsencrypt` son capaces de leer las etiquetas `VIRTUAL_HOST`, `LETSENCRYPT_HOST` y `LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL`. **Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo lo hacen y cómo puedo hacerlo yo?** Me gustaría usar esto en un dockerFile, pero me espero cualquier cosa...

Esta duda aparece por lo que aquí se explica [(nginx-proxy)](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda

LETSENCRYPT_HOST in:docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

##### UPDATE:

Encontre [este codigo](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/blob/master/app/letsencrypt_service_data.tmpl) entre los archivos de `letsencrypt` y algo similar entre los archivos de nginx(pero más largo). Creo que lo que estoy buscando es algo así, pero no se ni entiendo lo que hace exactamente

```
LETSENCRYPT_CONTAINERS=({{ range $host, $containers := groupBy $ "Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST" }}{{ range $container := $containers }} '{{ printf "%.12s" $container.ID }}' {{ end }}{{ end }})

{{ range $hosts, $containers := groupBy $ "Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST" }}

{{ range $container := $containers }}{{ $cid := printf "%.12s" $container.ID }}
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_HOST=( {{ range $host := split $hosts "," }}'{{ $host }}' {{ end }})
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_EMAIL="{{ $container.Env.LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL }}"
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_TEST="{{ $container.Env.LETSENCRYPT_TEST }}"
{{ end }}

{{ end }}
```

(Que use la variable `$containers` y que contenga `Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST` me da a entender que esta leyendo las `enviorement` declaradas en otros contenedores)

Comment: El ejemplo no muestra que un contenedor pueda leer variables de entorno de otro contenedor.

Comment: @emeeus ¿Como o con que puedo demostrarte que hace eso? Te puse el link de donde extraje la información y pregunto cómo hace eso que allí dice que hace. En la misma pregunta planteó que no se si es eso exactamente lo que hace o quiza está haciendo otra cosa que no soy capaz de ver/entender

Answer (score 1):

Cada contenedor está aislado a priori, ellos se pueden comunicar con el exterior a traves de los volúmenes y/o la red, la comunicación **entre** contenedores no escapa a estas formas. Desde afuera hacia adentro naturalmente existen otras formas como `docker exec`. En el ejemplo que incluyes no es evidente cual es la forma, pero si es que realmente lo hacen es alguna de esas.

Respecto a

> cómo puedo hacerlo yo?

Una forma de "reutilizar" las variables de entorno para varios contenedores es usando un archivo `.env` y pasarselo con el parámetro `env_file` a los contenedores que quieras:

```
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    env_file:
      - .entorno.env    
  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .entorno.env
```

En donde `entorno.env` puede ser algo como:

```
VIRTUAL_HOST=example.host.com
LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.host.com
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@mail.com
```

Existen muchisimas otras formas, que son mucho mas complicadas e inconvenientes. En lugar del tag `env_file` las variables se pueden exportar manualmente (`bash export VARIABLE=valor`) tomando los valores de un volumen comun, mas de un contenedor podría alterar el volumen afectando los demás. Se puede también hacer `ssh` y/o `scp` entre los contenedores, se pueden comunicar por `http`.. etc.

Comment: Buena teoría de `.env `, pero claramente no es lo que estoy preguntado. Tu respuesta seria más cercana si me hubieses explicado como como hacer variables de entorno "globales", que tampoco es lo que pregunto. Mi pregunta es: Como hace letsencrypt para leer la variable del contenedor nginx

Comment: Estimad@ @ICM, en principio no es ninguna teoría, en segundo lugar, dices "cómo puedo hacerlo yo?", pues bien, está es una forma. Te recuerdo además  que los que respondemos algunas preguntas no te debemos nada, lo hacemos porque queremos.

Comment: Perdón, quise decir "teórica", refiriéndome a que es una buena explicación sobre el `.env`. Realmente te agradezco el esfuerzo y el tiempo, pero creo que no es eso lo que busco y diría que lo he planteado bastante bien en la pregunta, si no es así te agradecería y recompensaria todas las modificaciones que creas convenientes